# iOS 11 animate largeTitleDisplayMode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios11

I am have a UITableView in a UIViewController that displays videos. When I scroll down, I would like to animate going from a large title to a small title. I currently use the code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, animations: {
                if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 128 {
                    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
                } else {
                    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

But it seems very jumpy when transitioning. What is a better way of doing this?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that. The title should change from small to large or vice versa automatically as you scroll.

Comment: Doesn't though. It might be because I'm using a UItableview inside a UIViewController

Comment: You should use UITableViewController for this case, if you don't want to use it see my answer

Answer (score 5):

If you're conforming to UITableViewDelegate add the following code:

```
var canTransitionToLarge = false

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    func animate(){
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()
        self.view.setNeedsLayout()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
    if canTransitionToLarge && scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0 {
        self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        animate()
        canTransitionToLarge = false
    }
    else if !canTransitionToLarge && scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {
        self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
        animate()
        canTransitionToLarge = true
    }
}
```

If not conforming to UITableViewDelegate add `ScrollViewDelegate` to your ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate
```